# error: Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hydrogen"

Tags: android-source

```
vamsi@vamsi:~/pie$ breakfast aosp_hydrogen-eng
including vendor/aosp/vendorsetup.sh
build/make/core/product_config.mk:234: error: Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hydrogen".
22:28:30 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
Device hydrogen not found. Attempting to retrieve device repository from PixelExperience-Devices Github (http://github.com/PixelExperience-Devices).
Repository for hydrogen not found in the PixelExperience-Devices Github repository list.
If this is in error, you may need to manually add it to your .repo/local_manifests/pixel.xml
build/make/core/product_config.mk:234: error: Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hydrogen".
22:28:31 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
build/make/core/product_config.mk:234: error: Can not locate config makefile for product "aosp_hydrogen".
22:28:32 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_hydrogen'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?


i have changed the device tree according to pixel

repo sync  

[CODE]Fetching projects:  99% (634/640)  Fetching project android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching project android_hardware_qcom_audio
Fetching project android_hardware_qcom_media
Fetching project android_hardware_qcom_media

Password for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/PixelExperience/android_device_xiaomi_hydrogen/'
Username for 'https://github.com': vamsikrishna999
Password for 'https://vamsikrishna999@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/PixelExperience/android_device_xiaomi_hydrogen/' not found

error: Cannot fetch android_device_xiaomi_hydrogen

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when i add new combo. The reason is thatt i set the wrong variable in AndroidProducts.mk file which is under the path of aosp/device/xxx/xxx/

> PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := \
>        $(LOCAL_DIR)/one_plus_one.mk